# Quickest Way To Send File To String And Back To File In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, blob

So in a client-side HTML page, a user selects a file and uploads it to the JavaScript code. JavaScript parses the file and sends it to the server and back to everyone else who is on the site. Then every client makes a blob download link for the file. It's easy when I can send the file to server and back like this.

But now, I want to make that file available for future users of the site without saving it to a location. This is in a chat program, so I've been sending messages from users as strings to a database. I'd like to create a program to send the aforementioned File object to the shortest string possible and then recreate the file (including all metadata) at another client from this string.

What is the standard way to convert a Blob to a string and back again without losing anything? If there's multiple ways, what results in the shortest string?

Comment: the "standard" way is by letting the browser handle a file upload and then storing that file on your server and then letting other users download it if you want to allow that. You MUST save it to a location and let your server / client handle file uploads /downloads if you want any type of performance.  There are plenty of static file servers that are cheap, easy to use and very high performance. Some files like images can be base 64 encoded, but every file can't be treated the same.  And even in the case of images, string translation performs terribly.  Files just aren't strings.

Comment: I'm not so sure there's any MUSTs in programming. I just asked for a standard way to convert a Blob to a string and back again, although I do know what you're talking about. I'm not that worried about performance.

Comment: there are plenty of musts in programming actually.  Like you must not divide by 0, it's illogical.  So is converting blobs to strings. They're simply NOT strings.

Comment: And I had sort-of accomplished this with the FileReader tool in JavaScript. I just thought there might be a better way to do this. For other reasons I'd prefer not to explain here I can't save anything to a location.

Comment: question asked and answered. good luck, voting to close.

Comment: Yeah, I did my research. You gave a great answer, just not to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, I had to modify some other answers from SO questions that only sorta applied to my question. Here's what I found:

This is on the uploading-client, in the function called when a file is uploaded:

```
let inp = document.getElementById("file_input");
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
    send_off_to_other_clients(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(inp.files[0]);
```

On the other clients:

```
<script>
    function get_blob_from_string (string, type, name) {
        let array = new Uint8Array(string.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
            array[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        let end_file = new Blob([array], {type: type, name: name});
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(end_file);
        a.download = name;
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.click();
    }
</script>
```

end_file is the returned-to-blob version, and then I create an anchor tag to download it. Probably isn't "proper" but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      console.log(reader.result) // save in a var!
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
```

[Credits](https://pqina.nl/blog/convert-a-file-to-a-base64-string-with-javascript/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34653143)